# nfkc 正規化で半角スペースに変わる文字たちだけを半角スペースに変更したい

Tags: python, unicode

[検索の際に全角のスペース記号がセパレータとして扱われていない](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3037/754)

メタの、上記のレポートをみていて、これは、一般的なシステムにおいてよくある問題な気がしました。というのも、日本人を対象にしたシステムであれば、スペースとして取り扱いたいものは、大体の場合において半角スペース(U+0020)と全角スペース(U+3000)ぐらいですが、これを、システムを i18n 化して取り扱うときには、各言語ごとにスペースっぽいものを定義して、それらをまとめてスペースと同じ処理を適用することになると思いました。

であるならば、もうちょっと汎用的にこの問題を解決したく、そこで考えたのが、 Unicode の NFKC 正規化変換をおこなったのちに、結果が半角スペースになるものを、一括してスペースとして取り扱う、というものです。

## 質問

ある文字列 s があったときに、 nfkc 正規化で半角スペースになる文字列のみを、実際に半角スペースに置換したいです。これは、どうやったら実現できるでしょうか？

Comment: リンクばかりなのでコメントで。5年前で29種類あるそうです。各言語のreplace関数で処理すれば出来るかも？ [Scalaで正規表現: ユニコードの空白文字29種類にマッチするか試してみた](https://qiita.com/suin/items/1a878dd3c7e7a4b14039), [Unicode spaces](http://jkorpela.fi/chars/spaces.html), [Regex Tutorial - Unicode Characters and Properties](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html), [Pythonのunicodedata.normalize('NFKC', x)で正規化される文字一覧](https://expectorate.hatenadiary.org/entry/20131230/1388433282), [ikegami-yukino/nfkc_compare.txt](https://gist.github.com/ikegami-yukino/8186853)

Comment: 追加で。[re --- 正規表現操作](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/re.html) `サードパーティの regex モジュールは、標準ライブラリの re モジュールと互換な API を持ちながら、追加の機能とより徹底した Unicode サポートを提供します。` [regex - PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/regex/), [Regular Expression Reference: Character Classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcharclass.html), [Character Classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html#class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unicode文字にはカテゴリが設定されており、U+0020もU+3000もSeparator, space (Zs)となっています。NFKCよりもこちらを使う方が簡単ですし、対応しやすいと思います。Perlや.NET、ES2018の正規表現では`\p{Zs}`で表現できます。残念ながらPythonには含まれていなさそうです。

改行などを含んでもよければ、[`\s`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/re.html#index-30)がU+3000を含みます。

> Unicode 空白文字 (これは `[ \t\n\r\f\v]` その他多くの文字、例えば多くの言語におけるタイポグラフィ規則で定義されたノーブレークスペースなどを含みます) にマッチします。 ASCII フラグが使われているなら、`[ \t\n\r\f\v]` のみにマッチします。